# Drop down list for multiple values and in a protected sheet for a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have this change event macro from a website, but it doesn't work in protected worksheets, I've tried using

`ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="secret"`

and then

`ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="secret"`

but it does not seem to work, i am very new at vba so I would highly appreaciate if you could help me with this. Also feel free to trash this out if you have something better.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 27 Then
  If Target.SpecialClls(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Many many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you invoking the protect/unprotect methods?

If you are adding the protect/unprotect calls to the Worksheet_Change sub it should look like below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
Activesheet.Unprotect Password:="secret"
If Target.Column = 27 Then
  If Target.SpecialClls(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

'Second Application.EnableEvents = True is redundant.
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Activesheet.Protect Password:="secret"

End Sub
```

If your sheet only needs to be protected from UI changes and NOT VBA changes, you can try running the protect sheet method with the UserInterfaceOnly parameter. This parameter is not permanent and does not remain when the workbook is closed, so you will need to write a Workbook_Open sub to apply it whenever the workbook is opened. Be sure to disable worksheet protection in the Excel interface.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws=thisworkbook.sheets("Sheetname")

ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```